# Specify the details form information

Tags: php, html, mysql

i want to get some information(email,vacancy id) from database.for that i used following code.i try to show retrieved data in a table using while loop.it was success,then i want to sent emails if user click send email button.every form contain different e mail addresses.but always emails are sent to one email address.that e mail address is which contain in last email address in DB.but i want to send that email to email addresses which contain that each form.help me to solve this.

```
<script src="..\js\jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="../PHP/sendemail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<table class="table" style="margin-bottom: 0">
<tbody>
<?php

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $_SESSION["imageno"] = $row['vacancyid'];
    //$row['email'];
    ?>
    <tr id="job">
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <img src="../comlogo/logo1.jpg" alt="Logo" style="width:100px;height:100px">&nbsp;<?= $row['company_name'];?>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-briefcase">&nbsp;</span><?=$row['catogary']; ?>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker">&nbsp;</span><?=$row['location'];?>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <input hidden type="text" id="email" name="email" value='<?= $row['email'];?>'>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 190px;padding-right: 0px ">

            <p>Posted Date:&nbsp;&nbsp;<?=$row['indate']; ?></p>
            <p>Expire Date:&nbsp;&nbsp;<?= $row['expdate'];?></p>
            <p>Remaining Days:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <?php
                        $date1=strtotime($row['expdate']);
                        $date2=strtotime(date("Y/m/d"));
                        $remainder=$date1-$date2;
                        $days=$remainder/86400;
    ?>
                <?=$days?></p>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 190px;padding-right: 0px ">

            <input type="file" name="uploaded_file" id="uploaded_file" class="text-center center-block well well-sm"><br>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" value="Apply Now" id="btn" name="btn">
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" value="" id="showprv" name="showprv" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Previwe</button>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <?php
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put the complete form tag inside the **while loop** in which you are fetching the details. It will be like...

```
 <?php
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
        $_SESSION["imageno"] = $row['vacancyid'];
    ?>
    <form action="../PHP/sendemail.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <?php
    <!-- Load all the data you want -->
    ?>
    </form>
    <?php } ?>
```

This will ensure that you send email to different e-mail addresses, not just the last one. With that your email problem will be solved.

Comment: when i use form tag inside while loop submit button not works

Comment: Use submit as the button type... something like this..... <input id="button" type="submit" value="Submit Form" />